# require appreview to get public feed from public facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get public feed from a public facebook page to show in our website. Do i need to submit my app for appReview? I have checked the below url

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{PAGE_NAME}/posts?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

I got response as below:

This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.

Is there any other method or api to get same data from facebook?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way, you can either user Page Token if you own the Page or you have to go through the review process for Page Public Content Access.

Comment: I own the page. How we get Page token?

Comment: I have developed using access token, which expires within a specific time.It works perfect. But when the token expires or change my password , API doesn't work anymore.What is the right method for feed integration?Never expiring token or Facebook App review.

Comment: if you own the page: use an extended page token. if you want to access the feed of other pages you do not manage: app review and app token.